# Prove the following claim regarding infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove that if $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} a_n^2 $ converges then also $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb N} \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}{n}$ converges?

Thanks !

Comment: $|ab|\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$. (Apply with $a=a_n$ and $b=1/n$.)

Comment: Alternatively: if it's not the case that $|a_n|/n \le a_n^2$, it follows that $|a_n|/n< 1/n^2$. So $|a_n|/n \le a_n^2 + 1/n^2$ for all $n$. Now use the Comparison Test.

Comment: David mitra- maybe you can write it as an answer so I can accept it? (the first reply )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding $(a-b)^2\ge0$ gives the inequality $|ab|\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$.

Apply this with $a=a_n$ and $b={1\over n}$ to obtain ${|a_n|\over n}\le{1\over2}(a_n^2+{1\over n^2})$ for every $n$.  Now you're set up nicely to use the Comparison Test.

(Alternatively: ${|a_n|\over n} \le( \max \{|a_n|, 1/n\})^2 \le |a_n|^2+{1\over n^2}$.)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

By [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{|a_n|}{n}\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2}.$$
Both sums on the right converge, so the partial sums of $\sum|a_n|/n$ are bounded and hence the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|a_n|}n\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\right)^{1/2}$$